# Managing unstructured text data into a DBMS

Tags: sql, database, text, nosql, text-mining

I'm competent in R and C++ and know my way around SQL queries, but not with databases and need some advice. Suppose I have a text file that looks like this:

```
# Full information about Amazon Share the Love products 
    Total items: 548552

    Id:   0
    ASIN: 0771044445
      discontinued product

    Id:   1
    ASIN: 0827229534
      title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler
      group: Book
      salesrank: 396585
      similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X
      categories: 2
       |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]
       |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]
      reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 5
        2000-7-28  cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK  rating: 5  votes:  10  helpful:   9
        2003-12-14  cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY  rating: 5  votes:   6  helpful:   5
```

for 500,000+ ids. I want to extract queries such as "what's the most popular book under category xxx?" or "which customer has the highest average helpful reviews?" or even suggest "which books would customer xxx enjoy?"

However, I do not know how to wrangle with this type of data. I was thinking of four databases/tables (what is the proper term!):

1. `Id` `ASIN` `title` `group` `salesrank` `num_of_similar` `num_of_categories` `total_reviews` `downloaded_reviews` `avg_rating_reviews`
2. `Id` `customer_name` `customer_date` `customer_rating` `customer_votes` `customer_helpful`
3. `Id` `category_name`
4. `Id` `similar`

Here is a snippet of what that would look like for the 3rd table (so you can deduce what I would imagine the 4th table to look like):

```
Id       category_name
1        Books
1        Subjects
1        Religion & Spirituality
```

However, I have no experiences with transforming unstructured text into databases and was looking for some guidance. Where do I start! Should I look into NoSQL! Or MS Access! Do I use for-loops to extract information (for instance, the category_name)? If so, how! Do I use regex? I have not found any beginner friendly tutorials on how to structure unstructured text into manageable databases, so any guidance would be severely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Entity-Attribute-Value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and triple stores (like RDF).

With similar use-case, I end up building [hoply](https://github.com/amirouche/hoply/).